# While loop won't print to dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, while-loop

I have written a snippet of code that allows me to work out either how many digits a number has or how many decimal places it has if it's value is below 1. I am then going to go on to do an if statement with the value calculated.

For example, my dataframe looks something like this

| Ticker | Level | Signal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAAA | 123 | 234 |
| BBBB | 0.123 | 0.234 |
| CCCC | 0.00123 | 0.00234 |

What I want is a new column that gives me a value that lets me know how many digits or decimal places there are so I can input that into my if function. I then know if digit = 0 for example, that means the number has 3 digits to the left of the decimal point. Here is an idea of my expected output.

| Ticker | Level | Signal | Digit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAAA | 123 | 234 | 0 |
| BBBB | 0.123 | 0.234 | 3 |
| CCCC | 0.00123 | 0.00234 | 5 |

The function that I have written works, however, when I try and output the value to my dataframe, it's filling the column with the value of the last row. So with the example above, all of the rows of the digit column say 5. Here is what I have so far with my code.

```
i = 0  
x = len(df.index)  
while i <= x-1:  
    level = df.iloc[i,3]  
    l = level/1000  
    l = str("{:.9f}".format(l))  
    digit = len(re.search('\d+\.(0*)', l).group(1))  
    print(digit)  
    print(level)  
    df['Digits'] = digit  
    i += 1
```

I have printed out the two values to make sure that the code itself works, which it does, but the new column "Digits" has the value 0 for every single row. When I try and output the variable level to the dataframe, it does the same thing and I can see that it is the last row that is being output each time throughout the dataframe.

Where am I going wrong?

Update:
I have managed to solve the issue. Someone wrote an answer to the question, but for some reason it has dissapeared. It is a different approach to mine, but does the job perfectly.

Rather than 1 value for each row, it's split the output into two columns, one for digits and one for decimals. I edited it slightly so that for the decimal column I get the number of zeros after the decimal point which is what I need for the next bit of code. This is now the output that I get.

| Ticker | Level | Digit | Decimal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAAA | 123 | 3 | 0 |
| BBBB | 0.123 | 0 | 0 |
| CCCC | 0.00123 | 0 | 2 |

This is now what my code looks like.

```
df['Digits'] = df['Level'].apply(lambda x: 0 if str(f"{x:.0f}")=='0' else len(str(f"{x:.0f}")))
df['Decimals'] = df['Level'].apply(lambda x: len(re.search('\d+\.(0*)', str("{:.9f}".format(x))).group(1)))
```

Thank you to whoever wrote the original answer and everyone else for your help and patience as I get to know how to use stack overflow. I promise my next question will be much better formatted.

Final update:
After more extensive testing the above code didn't fully work, so I adapted it one more time to give me one value for all rows. The final code is shown below.

```
df['Digits'] = (df['MACD Level (12, 26)']/1000).apply(lambda x: len(re.search('\d+\.(0*)', str("{:.9f}".format(x))).group(1)))
```

This now basically gives me a number that tells me how many digits a number has before or after the decimal point an example of which is shown in the table below.

| Digit | Meaning | Example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 digits before decimal place | 50.1 |
| 5 | 2 zeros after decimal place | 0.00345 |
| 7 | 4 zeros after decimal place | 0.0000875 |

Comment: Can you share that code in text format here  ?

Comment: Certainly can. This is what I have so far. The print(digit) and print(value) are just so I can see if the code is actually working. They are not needed.  

i = 0  
x = len(df.index)  
while i <= x-1:  
    level = df.iloc[i,3]
    l = level/1000
    l = str("{:.9f}".format(l))
    digit = len(re.search('\d+\.(0*)', l).group(1))
    print(digit)
    print(level)
    df['Digits'] = digit
    i += 1
df

Comment: That added code should be an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68455859/edit) to your question. It's hard to read in the comments. Also please please do not add `<br/>` to your code that will need to removed in order to run.

Comment: I think @cruisepandey requested you to edit your question and display your code there. It is easier to read your question that way.

Comment: Thank you all. I'll edit the question now. Apologies. I'm new to this.

Comment: `df['column'] = x` will assign the value `x` to all rows in `'column'`.

Comment: @Brendan, thank you, I understand that. What I am struggling with is why it is not adding a new value for each row. I am assuming I need to change the while loop, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I think if you added some [sample data and expected output](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (you can use `df.to_dict()` to generate a dictionary of your sample data frame that makes it easy for others to use it), it would be easier to provide a more specific response.

Comment: I have added some sample data and expected output as requested. Apologies for taking a while, I am still getting used to the formatting.

Comment: Maybe this could work: `df['LengthOfSignal'] = df['Signal'].astype(str).str.len()-2` for a new column?

Comment: That works in as far as the value is different for each row, however I'm not exactly sure what the number is telling me. Is it the total number of digits? If so, that doesn't solve my problem I'm afraid as not all the numbers have the same number of dp. Therefore the number 300.456 would look the same as the number 0.03004 which for my purposes doesn't work.

I need the number 300.456 to have a value that tells me it has 3 digits to the left of the decimal point and the number 0.03004 to have a value that tells me its first digit is 2 digits to the right of the decimal point.

Comment: I have managed to solve the problem with the help of another answer which has now dissapeared for some reason. I have added the solution above. Thanks everyone for your help.